# chunkeddownload error in trying to upgrade to Mac OS Mojave

Tags: macos, mojave

I have a Mac Mini Late 2014 model on macOS Sierra. I'm trying to upgrade it from macOS Sierra to Mojave using App Store. After clicking on installer, it gives me an error -

> The operation couldn't be completed.
>
> (com.apple.installer.chunkeddownload error 6.)

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: did you have many download interruptions ?

Comment: I don't think so. It downloaded the small 20 something MB installer. I clicked on it, it went fine all the way to "1 min remaining" and there it got stuck for sometime before throwing that error out.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. I downloaded Mojave from the app store and it too gave me the 22MB installer file. I was doing some research and found that was normal, and basically grabs the rest during the install. Im having the worst time just trying to upgrade to a SSD with a fresh install of MacOS. Ive deleted the install file and redownloaded from the app store and I get the same file. It downloaded that file fine, but during the install process, after choosing which hard drive i want to install on, I received this error approximately halfway through what was going to be a 5 hr install. I've booted and done this in safe mode and this is the furthest ive gotten.

I've just followed the link posted above by Buscar. That link gave me a link to the app store.  After deleting the file again, I downloaded it again from this path and I got the same result, 22.8MB file. I am attempting the install again.

Comment: What computer you are using? I'm using Mac Mini. I was finally able to get an install by using my home WiFi instead of Corporate WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong file to download.

Mojave is not 20 MB but a 6 GB file.

You can download it from here

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after several attempts, what worked for me was I deleted the existing 22MB downloaded in the launchpad and started a fresh installation.  It then download about 6.01GB file which installed without any issue.

Installation took about an hour or a little more to finish and now I am running on Mohave.